# Toshiba a10 tablet freezes at startup animation

Tags: android, tablet

My sister have a toshiba tablet, it is freezes at the startup animation.
I try to hard reset, but the problem is the same.
Probably an android upgrade can help, but I don't do this before.
Where can I find compatible Android 6?

What do you think? What will be the solution?
Hard situation, my niece can't see tales on the tablet.. :(

Best regards,
Feco

Comment: Try to boot the device with a charger connected. Old devices often have battery problems that lead to a crashing device.

Answer (score 0):

You could try doing a factory reset of the device, but all photos, apps, and data not backed up to the cloud will be lost.

To do that you go into recovery mode, normally by shutting the device off, and holding Power, Home (if a physical button), and Volume up.

From there, go to Factory Reset and follow the prompts.

Unfortunately though, there is a chance that the device has a hardware fault (I've had a few cheaper Android tablets have their flash storage fail), so even this might not work :(.

As for upgrading, to get Toshiba's official upgrades, if available, you'll probably have to boot into Android, and go to System Update via Settings.

As for more unofficial routes, LineageOS, which is the biggest and best supported third-party Android, doesn't support any Toshiba devices, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I done the factory reset, but nothing changed.
Can I download official android and install it from SD Card and recovery mode?

Comment: @user594297 Android is not an OS like Windows, you need a device specific firmware file as there are no general purpose installation images (at least not for your old device). Usually if your device with Internet connection does not offer an update there is not update for your device.

Comment: @Robert,  thanks! The problem is that the system can't load, because of the freeze..

Comment: My best guess then is that the flash storage or eMMC controller or whatever has failed. You might be out of luck